# Symfony2 + OneToMany + have to save data?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I have two entities :

KTH :

```
namespace Nauka\OneBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
* Nauka\OneBundle\Entity\Kth
*
* @ORM\Table(name="kth")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Kth
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $imie
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="imie", type="string", length=30)
 */
private $imie;

/**
 * @var string $nazwisko
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nazwisko", type="string", length=30)
 */
private $nazwisko;

/**
 *
 * @var integer $adres
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Adres", mappedBy="kth")
 */
private $adres;


public function __construct() {
    $this->adres = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function __toString() {
    return $this->nazwisko;
}
======= SET & GET functions =======
```

ADRES 
    namespace Nauka\OneBundle\Entity;

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Nauka\OneBundle\Entity\Adres
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Adres
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $ulica
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ulica", type="string", length=30)
 */
private $ulica;

/**
 * @var string $dom
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dom", type="string", length=5)
 */
private $dom;

/**
 *
 * @var type 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Kth", inversedBy="adres");
 */
private $kth;


public function __toString() {
    return $this->ulica;
}
=======SET & GET functions ===========
```

Kth form - KthType()

```
class KthType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
$builder
        ->add('imie')
        ->add('nazwisko')
            ->add('adres','collection',array(
                'type' => new AdresType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true
            ))
    ;
}
```

Adresy form - AdresType()

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
$builder
->add('ulica')
->add('dom');
}
```

Action in controller :

```
public function testAction(Request $request)
{

  $adres = new Adres();
  $kth = new Kth();

  $kth->getAdres()->add($adres);
  $formularz = $this->createForm(new KthType(), $kth);

  if($request->isMethod('POST'))
    {
      $formularz->bindRequest($request);
      $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
      $query->persist($formularz);
      $query->flush();
      return new Response('Done');
     } 

    return $this->render("NaukaOneBundle:Main:widok1.html.twig",array(
       'formularz' => $formularz->createView()
   )); 
}
```

And when i try to add something to database using Kth form - symfony give me :

```
The class 'Symfony\Component\Form\Form' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Nauka\OneBundle\Entity
500 Internal Server Error - MappingException
```

So can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't persist the `Form` instance, in your case `$formularz`.

What you intend to do, is actually to persist the entity, referenced by the `$kth` variable.

Replace your `if` block inside your controller action with:

```
if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $formularz->bindRequest($request)->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($kth);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response('Done');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now i have following error : 

    **Catchable Fatal Error: Method Nauka\OneBundle\Entity\Adres::__toString() must return a string value in C:\wamp\www\Nauka1\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException.php line 113**

Code from Adres entity, method __toString()
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->getUlica();
    }

Code : 
    `public function __toString() {
        return "test";
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you must persist a data of Form, not the Form..

```
if($request->isMethod('POST'))
{
  $formularz->bindRequest($request);
  $query = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
  $query->persist($formularz**->getData()**);
  $query->flush();
  return new Response('Done');
}
```

Comment: I tried to persist the form-data, I get no errors but couldnot save into the other table. Comparing the above case, I am able to save in the KTH entity but not in the Adres Entity.
Please Suggest.